# Variable hiding within nested let blocks in Boost Phoenix

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix, expression-templates, boost-proto

I'm having some trouble with nested let blocks in Boost Phoenix when an "inner" local variable hides an "outer" local variable. Even with the "Visibility" example from the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/scope/let.html), shown here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
using namespace phoenix::local_names;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  phoenix::let(_x = 1, _y = ", World")
  [
    phoenix::let(_x = "Hello") // hides the outer _x
    [
      std::cout << _x << _y // prints "Hello, World"
    ]
  ]();

  return 0;
}
```

I receive errors starting with:

```
GCC:   "error: function returning an array"
Clang: "error: function cannot return array type 'result_type' (aka 'char [6]')"
```

Does anyone know how I can "shadow" such a variable within the scope of an inner let block in Phoenix? I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04 with GCC version 4.8 snapshot; Clang 3.2; Boost 1.49; and also Boost 1.53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's most definitely a bug in Phoenix. The following compiles:

```
int y = 0;
int x = (phoenix::let(_a = 1, _b = 2)[phoenix::let(_b = _1)[ _a ]])(y);
```

The following does not:

```
int y = 0;
int x = (phoenix::let(_a = 1, _b = 2)[phoenix::let(_b = 3)[ _a ]])(y);
```

Bizarre. Could you file a bug at https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ (click "New Ticket"). Thanks. (Note: I'm not the maintainer.)